# How to see active session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I see the active sessions on my server? Is there a session table? I can't find it even if I do `psql` but from my reading there appears to be one. ([docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-expiry) and [article](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/))

I'm running Rails 5

Comment: Rails removed Active Record Session Store in Rails 4 since it's generally considered a bad idea and moved it to a gem.  High traffic sites would add a lot of read/write ops to your db. Why do you want to know which sessions are active?  There is probably a better way depending on your use case

Comment: @bkunzi01 i'm trying to debug an issue where users are getting logged out on mobile after ~2 hours. The CSRF token is coming back but we're losing the session...

Comment: Is the session set to expire?  Check in your initializers folder or production.env for something setting config.session_store with an expiration.  You should find something like:   

Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: ‘_some_session’, expires: 1.hour.from_now

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` storage by default. Where the session is simply stored in an encrypted cookie on the client. The client passes the cookies back with each request and the rails unencrypts the cookie and populations the session hash.

> How can I see the active sessions on my server?

**You can't.** The cookies are stored in the client. The server does not keep track of the clients that it issues cookies to. You would have to change to a different session storage which stores the session server side which is much slower.

There are several gems such as [Active Record Session Store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) which was removed in Rails 4 which provide server side session storage.

But this is most likely not a good fix for the problem you are actually trying to solve as they also rely on a cookie to tie the client to a server side session storage.

Comment: how does the server then decrypt the cookie? is it the _app_session? What is the call that it makes with that cookie to retrieve the session?

Comment: "What is the call that it makes with that cookie to retrieve the session?" - thats the sessions middleware.  https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try gem [authie](https://github.com/adamcooke/authie)

Modify your `User` model to associate with session:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sessions, :class_name => 'Authie::Session', :as => :user, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Then you can query the sessions from database.